# Let $a$ and $b$ be two complex numbers such that $|a+b|=20$ and $|a^2+b^2|=16$ then find maximum and minimum value of $|a^3+b^3|$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be two complex numbers such that

$|a+b|=20$ and

$|a^2+b^2|=16$

then find maximum and minimum value of $|a^3+b^3|$

**My Attempt:**

$|a^3+b^3|=|(a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab|)\leq |a+b|^3+3|ab|$

Couldn't go beyond this

Comment: The second equality gives some bounds on $|ab|$ which can be useful here.

Comment: Note that $|(a+b)^2|=|a^2+2ab+b^2|=400$, so $a^2$ and $b^2$ must almost cancel.  Also you can assume $a$ is real by dividing out its phase factor.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan I could obtain the maximum value as $4480$ using your Hint above but can't find the minimum value

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868669/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|a+b|=20\iff a+b=20e^{it}\iff ae^{-it}+be^{-it}=20$

So WLOG we can replace $a,b$ by phase shifted ones and  assume $a+b=20$.

We also have $|a^2+b^2|=16\iff a^2+b^2=16e^{i\theta}$

$\begin{align}\Big|a^3+b^3\Big|
&=\Big|(a+b)^3-\tfrac 32(\underbrace{(a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)}_{2ab})(a+b)\Big|\\
&=\Big|20^3-\frac 32((20^2-16e^{i\theta})\times 20\Big|\\\\
&=\Big|480e^{i\theta}-4000\Big|\\\\
&=160\sqrt{634-150\cos(\theta)}\end{align}$

- The minimum is when $\cos(\theta)=1\iff \theta=0$ and the value is $3520$

Initial values would be $\begin{cases}a+b=20\\a^2+b^2=16\end{cases}\iff a,b=10\pm 2i\sqrt{23}$

- The maximum is when $\cos(\theta)=-1\iff \theta=\pi$ and the value is $4480$

Initial values would be $\begin{cases}a+b=20\\a^2+b^2=-16\end{cases}\iff a,b=10\pm 6i\sqrt{3}$